# request for clarification in snakemake's documentation regarding 'resources' and 'threads'

Tags: snakemake, lsf

I have a question with regards to resources and threads (it's not clear to me [from the documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#resources)).
Are the resources *per thread* ?

That's the case with various HPC job submission systems. E.g.: that's for example how jobs work on LSF's bsub:

- If I request 64 threads, with 1024MiB each, bsub will schedule a job with 64 process, each consuming 1024MiB individually, and thus consuming 64GiB in total.

  (That total memory may or may not be on the same machine, as the 64 processes may or may not be on the same machine depending on the `host[span=n]` parameters. For openMPI uses it might well be 64 different machines each allocating it's own local 1024MiB chunk. But with `host[span=1]`, it's going to be a single machine with 64 threads and 64GiB memory).

When looking at the LSF profile, `mem_mb` [seems to passed with only unit versions but otherwise the same value from ressources to bsub](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/lsf/blob/c88fcb9fc60ce74596fbf8f516fef31574eef5de/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.profile_name%7D%7D/lsf_submit.py#L87)
thus it seems that snakemake and LSF both assume that *total_memory = threads * mem_mb*.

I just wanted to make sure this assumption is correct.

---

Upon further analysis, the [resources accounting in jobs.py](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/0aae52faefbbf195f11f5545b337042284633547/snakemake/jobs.py#L1186) is in contactiction of the above.

Filing a bug request